# Adding multiple authors to Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to add a list of authors to a Table of Contents but it is not working for some reason. I thought that, as it was been written to a file, the list needed to be protected but that does not seem to work.

It is a bit long but here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, onecolumn, final]{book}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



%%% Code to add multiple authors to a chapter and to the TOC
\newcounter{chapterauthornum}
\newcounter{authorlstnum}
\newcounter{authorcounter}


%% Create variables to save author and institution information
\newcommand\chapterauthors[2]{%
    \stepcounter{chapterauthornum}
    \protect\expandafter\def\csname chapterauthorsname\thechapterauthornum\endcsname{\protect{#1}}
    \protect\expandafter\def\csname chapterinstsname\thechapterauthornum\endcsname{\protect{#2}}
}

%% Command to print author and institution list below the chapter heading and generate the author list for the TOC
\newcommand\printauthorlist{
%%% Print author list with institutions
    \getauthorchapterlist % List bleow chatper heading
%%% Add authors to Table of Contents
    \printauthortoclist % Prints list for testing
    \makeauthortoclist % Adds list of authors to Table of Contents
    \setcounter{chapterauthornum}{0} % Resets everything for next chapter
}


%% Generates the list that goes below the chapter headng
\newcommand\getauthorchapterlist{%
   \setcounter{authorlstnum}{\value{chapterauthornum}}
   \setcounter{authorcounter}{0}

   \loop
      \ifnum\value{authorlstnum}>0 %
         \stepcounter{authorcounter}
         {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-15pt}%
         \linespread{1.1}
         \raggedleft\large\bfseries\itshape
         \csname chapterauthorsname\theauthorcounter\endcsname
         \par\nobreak\vspace*{15pt}
         }
        {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-15pt}%
         \linespread{1.1}
         \raggedleft\normalfont
         \csname chapterinstsname\theauthorcounter\endcsname
         \par\nobreak\vspace*{20pt}
         }
         \addtocounter{authorlstnum}{-1}
   \repeat
\par\nobreak\vspace*{10pt}
}

%% Generate the list of authors that will go into the Table of Contents
\newcommand\makeauthortoclist{%
%    \protect
    \forloop{authorcounter}{1}{\value{authorcounter} < \value{chapterauthornum}}
    {\expandafter\csname chapterauthorsname\theauthorcounter\endcsname, \relax}
    {and \expandafter\csname chapterauthorsname\thechapterauthornum\endcsname}
}


%% use the list of authors generated and adds them to the Table of Contents
\newcommand{\printauthortoclist}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
%    \vskip-5mm
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    % \hskip1.3em\mdseries\itshape\protect\scriptsize
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize\makeauthortoclist}{}{}}
}



\title{Models and Reality}
\author{John Dobleman}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter{A Probabilistic Analysis}
\chapterauthors{Gilna Samuel}{Department of Finance, Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute}
\chapterauthors{Cornelius Longbottom}{Department of Magic and Tchnology, MIT}
\chapterauthors{Nat Granger}{Department of Muggle Integration, Ministry of Magic}
\printauthorlist

\section{Magic and what it means}
\lipsum[1-3]



\end{document}
```

So the problem is that while the list is generated like I want it to, it is not being added to the Table of Contents; only the last author is being added. I know that it is being generated because I added the list below in the body of the text.

I suspect it has something to do with how I am using csname. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `chapterauthorsname\thechapterauthornum` will yield `chapterauthorsname1` (although I'm not sure if `\thechapterauthornum` would even be expanded inside the `\csname` constructin) and I guess the 1 gets ignored as macros should only consist of letters.

Comment: No, that is not the problem. `\csname chapterauthorsname\thechapterauthornum\endcsname` works as expected. See the answer for the real problem and its solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the argument to `\addtocontents` is a moving argument (it is moved to the table of contents), and the `\forloop` that is used in the argument is fragile (it contains "assignments").

`\forloop` is meant to print text, not to collect text in an argument. You have to do that in a different way, either by collecting it in a macro, that is used as a variable, or in a token register.

Here is the solution with a macro:

```
\newcommand\authortoclist{}
\newcommand\addto[2]{%
      \edef#1{#1#2}}%
%% Generate the list of authors that will go into the Table of Contents
\newcommand\makeauthortoclist{%
  \def\authortoclist{}
    \forloop{authorcounter}{1}{\value{authorcounter} < \value{chapterauthornum}}
    {\addto\authortoclist{\expandafter\csname chapterauthorsname\theauthorcounter\endcsname, }}
    \addto\authortoclist{and \expandafter\csname chapterauthorsname\thechapterauthornum\endcsname}
}
%% To print the list of authors, just use \makeauthortoclist \authortoclist

%% use the list of authors generated and adds them to the Table of Contents
\newcommand{\printauthortoclist}{%
  \makeauthortoclist
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \vskip-2mm
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize \authortoclist}{}{}\vskip2mm}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked. One final question so I understand this correctly. Basically, what I was doing wrong was that the `\addtocontents` was a different type of argument to the type of argument I was trying to create using the `\forloop` command, and that is the reason it did not work?

Comment: Yes, the `\forloop` generates text that goes to the output (say the PDF file). The `\addtocontents` however, writes its argument to the `.toc` file. But as you had it, it did not write the authors to the `.toc` file, but the `\forloop` itself. When the `\tableofcontents` is printed in the next LaTeX run, it will execute the `\forloop` but then the macros containing the author info are no longer present (or not yet present). Only the last one is present because that is outside the `\forloop`.

Comment: This solution is still not robust, see my other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with a token register instead of macro. The solution with the macro is still not robust because of the `\edef` in the `\addto` macro. It works if the authors and institution contain only ASCII characters but it fails if there are accented characters. To make a robust solution is a bit more work but here it is:

```
\newtoks\authortoclist
\newcommand\action{}
\newcommand\addto[2]{%
      \toks0={#2}
      \edef\action{\noexpand#1={\the#1\the\toks0}}%
      \action}

%% Generate the list of authors that will go into the Table of Contents

\newcommand\makeauthortoclist{%
  \authortoclist={}
    \forloop{authorcounter}{1}{\value{authorcounter} < \value{chapterauthornum}}
    {\expandafter\addto\expandafter\authortoclist\expandafter{\csname chapterauthorsname\theauthorcounter\endcsname, }}
    \addto\authortoclist{and }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\authortoclist\expandafter{\csname chapterauthorsname\thechapterauthornum\endcsname}
}

%% To print the list of authors, just use \makeauthortoclist \the\authortoclist

%% use the list of authors generated and adds them to the Table of Contents
\newcommand{\printauthortoclist}{%
  \makeauthortoclist
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \vskip-2mm
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize \the\authortoclist}{}{}\vskip 2mm}
}
```